# android download files problem

Tags: android

i wanna download files in my application ,

so i used threads to download ,

but i found that if i close application , the  downloading stopped.

should i use 「service」 to implement downloading?? or something else ??

could someone give me suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should use service with new thread running on it. If you implement service downloading will not crashed when you close app.